# How do I set up GeoServer for large datasets

Tags: geoserver, geotiff

I'm trying to setup GeoServer to display 2 data stores.  Both are full Earth tile sets, 1 for Day and 1 for night.  The imagery is 200m which roughly translates to 2x 50 1.2GB GeoTiffs.  For context, the application this a museum exhibit that simulates the view from the Space Station.  Tiles need to load quickly and often times for large areas if we're going to provide an oblique view (looking over the horizon).  We're using CesiumJS for the renderer which has support for most of the imagery provider standards out there.

Steps I've tried already tried:

ImageMosaic. I can't load Zoom Levels 0-4 without the server running out of memory.  At the further zoomed out levels I get a stupendously blurry image and it takes minutes for it to return the actual high-resolution tiles.  I have caching on and I've even run the seeding process.

ImagePyramid: Using GDAL I built an ImagePyramid with 11 layers for each of the tile sets.  This seemed to help a little, but seems to have capped the resolution greatly.

At this point I can only assume I need to do some fancy hybrid configuration of the 2, but I'm at a loss for where to actually start or if there is actually just a defacto way these sorts of configurations are handled.

Comment: I'd have tried jpeg compression and ybrc colour space see ianturton.com/tutorial/bluemarble

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got anyone that is interested the solution that worked best is to merge the tiles together and use gdal2tiles to create a TMS server.